# Apache Lucene Version

Tags: apache, lucene, version, yelp

I am just starting a student project for a lesson **based on apache lucene** and the data that i am going to process with this tool is **critics about restaurants from yelp.**

What version do you recommend as the most stable for this purpose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that if you are starting from scratch there's no reason to use an old version. Use the latest version (8.0). Lucene releases are always very stable in my experience.